# Dynamic Menu in Angular with JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, menu

I need to create a dynamic angular menu using json parameters. I was seeing answers to similar questions and saw that they used ng-repeat to achieve it.

Actually i achieve using 100% code but this limit the use.

Using angular 8 and json paramtrs

```
this.modulos = [{
            name: 'Primary menu',
            icon: 'fa-map',
            style: {'color': 'red'},
            submenu: [
                {
                    name: 'Submenu 1',
                    style: {'color': 'red'}
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            name: 'Submenu Submenu 1',
                            style: {'color': 'red'}
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Submenu Submenu 2',
                            style: {'color': 'red'}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Submenu 2',
                    style: {'color': 'red'}
                    submenu: [
                        {
                            name: 'Submenu Submenu 1',
                            style: {'color': 'red'}
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Submenu Submenu 2',
                            style: {'color': 'red'}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: 'Submenu 3',
                    style: {'color': 'red'}
                    submenu: []
                }
            ]
        }]
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class="parent scrollbar">
        <li class="main">
            <i class="fa fa-bars" id="nav-bar"></i> <span> Menú</span>
        </li>
        <li class="item" id="active">
            <div style="display:flex;align-items: center;">
<i class="fa fa-home"></i>  <span> Primary Title with submenu </span></div>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li>
                    <b>Scondary title with submenu</b>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li>This is a submenu of submenu</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I hope to create a menu regardless of the json content

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by regardless of content? Obviously there are structures that you cannot accommodate.

Comment: The idea is to create a menu from a json file, being able to handle its structure with greater dynamism. This menu would take the json and be created following the parent-child structure

Comment: So what's your question exactly?

Comment: There is some attribute of html in angular that is used in these cases. I was watching and using ng-repeat.

Comment: You haven't explained where it stopped working.